# How to perform button click in angular which is to be rendered?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a add button which when clicked adds an element in an array. I've another show button which has ngIf directive and is shown checking if the length of array is greater than 0. When I click on add button assuming that the element is added in array how do I perform click on show button via code as the show button is not yet present in dom.

Following is the code I've written in html for show button-

```
<button id="show" *ngIf="myArray.length > 0" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:15px;align-items:center" (click)="Show(optionForm.valid)">Show</button>
```

following is the sample code on add button click event -

```
Add(valid: boolean | null) {
this.myArray.push(someElement);
document.getElementById("show")?click();
}
```

Comment: You probably need to inject a `ChangeDetectorRef` and call its `DetectChanges()` method.

Comment: any lead on how i can implement this?

Comment: Why are you clicking on buttons in the DOM from your component?  What does `Show()` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to let DOM make the button.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  document.getElementById("show").?click();
}, 0)
```

[here is the stackblitz example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3nu21t?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html)